Remote desktop licensing mode is not configured
We have a Windows 2019 Server. It is workgroup server & not part of domain. Its been running fine since 3 to 4 years. We are seeing below message when trying to RDP to server since last 3 months. 2 concurrent RDP connections are enough & we dont need more than 2. Hence, dont need any CAL or user licenses.
Please guide on how to fix this issue so that we will be able to RDP even after grace period.
Please note that I have tried stopping Remote Desktop services in order to troubleshoot the issue. But, my RDP connection immediately got disconnected & I was unable to RDP. To fix this RDP issue, opened services.msc in my laptop & with 'connect to another computer' option, I connected to server's services.msc & started Remote Desktop services again. I was then able to RDP. So, realized RDS need to be running in order to RDP.enter image description here
enter image description here

2 concurrent RDP connections are enough & we dont need more than 2. Hence, dont need any CAL or user licenses. you don't need licenses for remote administration, which is not what you have. Your system was setup incorrectly. Also, the error isn't about licenses at all. It's about the license server that must exist. It doesn't need licenses and never has, unless you have per computer licensing configured.

Remove the RDS roles from the server. They are not needed for administrative RDP sessions.

Use GPEDITS.MSC, and select it there on the two hosts;
Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Remote Desktop Services > Remote Desktop Session Host > Licensing.
Set it to Users mode in your case.

NOTE: Running without licence is breaching the agreement with Microsoft.
